# I want my structure of vehicle makes to show in a listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm not sure what to change in my code to make the listbox show each vehicle make.

```
Public Class Form1

Structure Vehicle
    Dim Make As String
    Dim Model As String
    Dim Doors As Integer
    Dim Hp As Integer
    Dim VIN As String
End Structure




Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Dim Vehicles(9) As Vehicle

    Vehicles(0).Make = "Chevrolet"
    Vehicles(1).Make = "Dodge"
    Vehicles(2).Make = "Nissan"
    Vehicles(3).Make = "Mitsubishi"
```

Made a for loop to show each make

```
    For i = 0 To 4 Step 1
        ls.Items.Add(Vehicles(i).Make.ToString)

    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: For one thing, you don't need to call `ToString` on a `String`.  Apart from that, in what way is this not working?

Comment: without the .tostring i get "Value cannot be null."

Comment: with the tostring I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: you need a  Vehicles(4).Make = "Something"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only supplying data to 4 instances (0-3):

```
Vehicles(0).Make = "Chevrolet"
Vehicles(1).Make = "Dodge"
Vehicles(2).Make = "Nissan"
Vehicles(3).Make = "Mitsubishi"
```

But you're trying to retrieve data from 5 instances (0-4):

```
For i = 0 To 4 Step 1
```

`String` is by default `Nothing` unless you assign it a value.  So your 5th instance is an empty instance of `Vehicle`.  Thus...

This will fail because `Vehicles(4).Make` is `Nothing`, and you can't call a method (`ToString`) on `Nothing`:

```
ls.Items.Add(Vehicles(i).Make.ToString)
```

And this will fail because `Vehicles(4).Make` is `Nothing`, and you can't add an empty or null string to a listbox:

```
ls.Items.Add(Vehicles(i).Make)
```

You need to either:

- Adjust your loop to only cover the data you have (`For i = 0 To 3 Step 1`), or
- Add another data element (`Vehicles(4).Make = "Something"`), or
- Add null checking to your code (`If Vehicles(i).Make Is Not Nothing`)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using `Class` instead of `Structure`, and using `list` instead of `array`. Since it seems that yourself also don't how long will the data be, so in this case `list` is a good choice for your and you can just consider it as a dynamic array in c/c++. Following is my way to interpret

```
Public Class Form1

Class Vehicle
    Dim Make As String
    Dim Model As String
    Dim Doors As Integer
    Dim Hp As Integer
    Dim VIN As String

Public Sub New(Dim s As String)
    Me.Model=s
End Sub
End Class




Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    btnGo.Click
Dim Vehicles As New List(Of Vehicle)

Vehicles.Add(New Vehicle("Chevrolet"))
Vehicles.Add(New Vehicle("Dodge"))
Vehicles.Add(New Vehicle("Nissan"))
Vehicles.Add(New Vehicle("Mitsubishi"))
```

And when you loop it,

```
Dim car as Vehicle
For each car in Vehicles
    ls.Items.Add(car.Make)
Next
```

Hope it helps.